# How filter GroupVariables by variable name in the Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get%20variable%20groups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) I can get a specific variable group using the below request

```
GET .../_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?groupName={groupName}
```

This returns all the variables for a specific Variable Group.

I'd like to get the details for a specific variable so I don't have to download all of them.
e.g

```
GET .../_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?groupName={groupName}&VariableName={MyName}
```

I've searched but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I also do not think we can use the API to get the name or value of the variablegroups directly. We have to manually use the script to parse the JSON file to get the name or value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get only one variable, all the idea that it's a group and currently the Rest API let you get the group.

But if you use PowerShell you can filter the results easily when you perform the Rest:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?groupName={name}&api-version=5.0"
$varName = "MyName"
$varValue = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json).value.variables.$varName
```